# If an NORDO airplane approaches and attempts a landing on a controlled airport, is that an automatic emergency?

Tags: emergency, lost-communications

The airplane never has any communication with ATC etc. but approaches and heads for landing correctly on a controlled airport will that by regulations automatically lead to clearing airspace and airport?

Comment: If it's VFR nordo and it enters controlled airspace (C or B), they are not "landing correctly". Are you talking about IFR operations?

Comment: Please also specify the region you are asking about.

Comment: @RonBeyer It’s legal if it’s the best option in an emergency, which is assumed if you’re 7600. It’s just rare that a B/C airport is the best option since they tend to be ringed by D/E/G airports.

Comment: @StephenS, Ron isn't saying it is illegal, he notes, (in quotes) that they are not landing correctly - meaning they haven't established comms per normal FAA procedures.  Yes, it is legal in an emergency, but whether it is an emergency hasn't been answered because the question hasn't been clarified!

Comment: @StephenS - In the US, an IFR NORDO aircraft following its flight plan would be “landing correctly” per the FAR/AIM. There are no provisions for a VFR NORDO aircraft to land at a controlled airport without establishing two-way communications. Light-gun signals count. If it is an emergency, the pilot can land wherever he can. Squawking 7500, 7600, or 7500 is recommended, but not required.

Comment: Either way, a NORDO aircraft is not an emergency. A VFR aircraft is not required to have a radio.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, NORDO isn't an emergency. As StephanS says in his answer, if you are IFR you continue on your flight plan as filed.

However VFR is the issue... If you are outside Class B or C airspace and you enter Class B or C without clearance, you've violated the airspace. If you have other emergency-level problems and NORDO is just a symptom of that, sure, squawk 7700 and cautiously continue, however I would not ever enter Class B in this circumstance, the potential for major conflicts is just too high.

If you are already in the Class C/B, then you should continue and watch for light-gun signals.

ATC is typically on the ball and will clear airspace around you, but in the post-9/11 world if you violate a Class B area VFR and do not indicate emergency or other issue, expect either a fighter escort or at the very least, a phone number to call when you get on the ground.

Your pilot training included a lot of "lost comms" procedures, you can try listening in on the VOR frequency. If you get low enough, use your cell phone to call the tower. If you only have one radio in the first place, you should be flying with a hand-held backup. Sometimes transmit fails but receive works, so listen to the frequencies and comply with any requests. Try to find a non-towered airport to land at and call the airport you want to go to for prior clearance. There are a dozen things you can do before you violate airspace, do those first, then think about proceeding without clearance.

Answer (score 0):

In an emergency, everything is legal. If your emergency is a radio failure, then squawk 7600 and ATC will recognize the emergency, clear the airspace around you and use light gun signals to clear you to land. But you’re probably better off landing at a non-towered airport where being NORDO isn’t an emergency in the first place.

If you’re squawking 1200/7000 (depending on region), ATC will likely assume you’re just an idiot (or student pilot) who didn’t realize the airport was towered. It happens. They’ll still clear the airspace around you to keep everyone else safe, and they’ll still try light gun signals just in case, but your experience *after* landing will probably be quite different.

Answer (score 0):

A better context isn't "emergency," but whether the aircraft is given priority.  An emergency may be declared by a pilot, or by a controller, but in either case, the salient intent is to request, and to give priority.  If an aircraft is given priority, it doesn't really matter whether a formal "emergency" declaration is made.  It's about priority.

An aircraft arriving at a controlled airport without any communication will be given priority by necessity.  If the controller cannot communicate with, and thus control the inbound aircraft, he will communicate with everyone else and move them, delay them, turn them, stop them, or clear them as necessary to prevent a collision or unsafe condition.

An aircraft with a communication failure may continue per the flight plan and or clearance and land, and will be given the priority necessary until it can be determined down and clear.  If the failure occurs in visual conditions, the aircraft should divert and land where able without causing an emergency, and notify air traffic control of the failure.

It's important to note that in an emergency, everything is NOT "legal."  One may only deviate from the regulation to the extent necessary to meet the demands of emergency.  One may deviate from any regulation to meet those demands, but should take care not to exceed that necessary, or to abuse the moment.  An emergency, declared or otherwise, is not carte blanche to violate the regulations, or do as one pleases.